# How to map a friend request entity in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

i am creating a small social media, but i don't know the best way to map the friends request entity. if it should me a many to one or a one to many, since the friend request class references the user entity class twice. one for receiver of the request and one for the sender of the request. please can you help me look at my code and see if i am doing the right thing?

```
    @Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends DefaultEntity {


    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    @NotNull(message = "Enter a FirstName")
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name = "LastName")
    @NotBlank(message = "Enter a LastName")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(unique = true,name = "UserName")
    @NotBlank(message = "Enter a UserName")
    private String userName;


    @Column(unique = true, name = "Email")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter an Email address")
    @Email(message = "Enter a valid Email")
    private String email;


    @Column(name = "Password")
    @NotBlank(message = "Enter a Password")
    private String password;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "Gender")
    private Gender gender;


    @Column(name = "Address")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your Home Address")
    private String address;


    @Column(name = "Country")
    @NotBlank(message = "Please enter your Country")
    private String country;


    @Column(name = "Picture")
    private String picture;


    @Column(unique = true, name = "PhoneNumber") //make this accept only numbers
    private String phoneNumber;


    @Column(name = "Bio")
    private String bio;


    @Column(name = "OnlineStatus")
    private OnlineStatus onlineStatus;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "UserType")
    private UserType userType;


    @Column(name = "Money")
    private long money;


    //@MapsId()
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "playerstats")
    private PlayerStats playerStats;
}
```

and here is the friend request entity:

```
   @Component
@Entity
@Table(name = "FriendRequest")
public class FriendRequest extends DefaultEntity {

    private User sender;

    private FriendRequestStatus friendRequestStatus;

    private User recipient;

    public User getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(User sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public User getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    public void setRecipient(User recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    public FriendRequestStatus getFriendRequestStatus() {
        return friendRequestStatus;
    }

    public void setFriendRequestStatus(FriendRequestStatus friendRequestStatus) {
        this.friendRequestStatus = friendRequestStatus;
    }
}
```

Please is my friend request entity especially the user objects in it mapped properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the association between a request and its sender. A request has one sender. Otherwise the sender field would be a collection of users, and would be named `senders`. So it can't possibly be a ToMany association: it refers to *one* user.

Now, is it a OneToOne or a ManyToOne? Can multiple requests be sent by the same user. I gess so. A life where everyone can have only one friend would be a little sad, wouldn't it? So, multiple requests can refer to the same sender or, if you prefer, a user can send multiple requests. So it's a ManyToOne.

I'll let you do the reasoning for the other association.

Note that annotating your entities with Component makes absolutely no sense. Those are not Spring beans. Spring does not instantiate them nor inject them.

Comment: but then my problem is that i have a sender who is a user and a receiver who is also a user, dont i have to annote this objects with onetoone or somthing like that, because if i persist i am afraid it may not store the users ID in the database?

Comment: i annoted it component so i can autowire it in a controller based on a book i read, or is there a better option?

Comment: i annoted it component so i can autowire it in a controller based on a book i read, or is there a better option?

Comment: Of course you need to annotate both of them. But not with OneToOne, as my answer explains.

Comment: Why would you autowire a User in a controller? Which one of the potentially thousands of users in your database would be injected by Spring? What would this injected user be used for? If the book really told you to do that with JPA entities, you'd better read another book.

Comment: i taught autowiring was meant to escape the rigidity of User user = new User();

Comment: When a controller (which is a singleton, who lives from the start of the app to its end), needs a service (which is also a singleton, living from the start of the app to its end), using dependency injection is useful to help testing, apply AOP, etc. But entities are completely different. They are short-lived objects, you need to create many of them (each time you need to save a new User to the DB), and are not created or managed by Spring, since JPA creates them whe getting them out of the database.

Comment: okay, so are you saying i should initialize them the traditional java way "User user = new User()" ??

Comment: okay, so are you saying i should initialize them the traditional java way "User user = new User()" ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. And they should not be instance variables of controllers or services. That also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: wooow, i will do that, just gonna be a long revamping of code. Thanks alot, i appreciate.

Comment: but i am still not sure about the one to many, can you help me with an example or a snippet of a modified version of mine ?

Comment: but i am still not sure about the one to many, can you help me with an example or a snippet of a modified version of mine ?

Comment: `@ManyToOne private User sender;` Really, this is fundamental stuff. Read the hibernate manual about associations (in fact, read it completely). Also read the answer I gave you. Its whole point is to tell you it's a ManyToOne, and yet you're asking first about "one to one or something", and now about "one to many".

Comment: thanks, i did the @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="sender")
    private User sender;

Comment: The targetEntityClass is useless. Your field is of type User, so JPA knows that the target entity class is User.

Comment: ohh ohh, alright alright...will remove that too, thanks Sir!